# Eclipse error: JRE is selected, but the path is invalid

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, weblogic12c

I have a Java web application I work on using an Eclipse IDE.  I'm using WebLogic 12c.

I recently had the jdk upgraded from jdk1.7.0_55 to jdk1.7.0_79.

Since then, I can't get anything to build; and I can't even start my local WebLogic server.

I reset my JAVA_HOME environment variable to the new path, and I also opened the properties of the project - and set the JRE System Library to jdk1.7.0_79.

However, no dice.  If I try to build using my ANT script, I get the following error:

[image]

So it's obviously still looking for the old jdk1.7.0_55 installation - but I don't know why or where.

Then if I even try to start the localhost server, I get this

[image]

If I try to add a new server, I get the same error.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your weblogic installation (or more exactly, in your domain), check the file setDomainEnv.cmd. Weblogic stores some absolute paths to the jdk itself. You will have to edit this file manually.

Sample paths from my machine for comparison:

```
wls12130\user_projects\domains\mydomain\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd (3 hits)
    Line 46: set SUN_JAVA_HOME=C:\develop\jdk1.8.0_66
    Line 48: set DEFAULT_SUN_JAVA_HOME=C:\develop\jdk1.8.0_66
    Line 65:        set JAVA_HOME=C:\develop\jdk1.8.0_66
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had to run External Tools Configuration a number of times and a few other things as well - but you definitely put me on the right path!

Answer (score 2):

Try this... In Eclipse, go to the Servers menu and right click 'New.' In the 'New Server' window find the 'Configure runtime environments' link ([See Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvkmd.jpg)) and once there you then click the server that needs the updated JRE upgrade and then Click 'Edit'. In the Edit Server Runtime Environment Window there should be a Java home textfield where you can put the jdk that you upgraded to. ([See Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51I8r.jpg))

NOTE: This was done in Eclipse Kepler in the time of this writing. Should work in later versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the WebLogic installation and let it know where to find the new JDK.

Unfortunately, the JDK path is written into several configuration files, both in the Domain and in the Weblogic installation directory. And also in the directories of other products that are part of Oracle Fusion Middleware.

Here is a sample list of files that may need to be updated if you change the JDK installation directory:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/install/envVars.properties
$ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin/commEnv.sh
$ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin/setHomeDirs.sh
$ORACLE_HOME/oui/.globalEnv.properties  (12.2.1)
$ORACLE_HOME/oui/bin/compareInventory.sh
$ORACLE_HOME/oui/bin/install.sh
$ORACLE_HOME/oui/bin/viewInventory.sh
$ORACLE_HOME/wlserver/.product.properties

$DOMAIN_HOME/bin/setDomainEnv.sh
$DOMAIN_HOME/bin/setNMJavaHome.sh  (12.2.1)
$DOMAIN_HOME/nodemanager/nodemanager.properties
```

**References** (provided without links, because links into the Oracle site tend to decay rapidly):

How to Install and Maintain the Java SE Installed or Used with FMW 11g/12c Products (Doc ID 1492980.1)

How to Upgrade the JDK Used by Oracle WebLogic Server 12c to a Different Version (Doc ID 1616397.1)